# FFTW performance variation

Tags: c++, c, fft, fftw

I'm using FFTW3 in a program to do some work on 2D arrays (roughly 3k x 3k, complex data type).

The most intense portion of the program basically does this:

```
Break the array up into N threads, each thread has the following

loop
{
    Fill one of three buffers depending on what I'm doing
    FFT forward on that buffer
    Do some work
    FFT backward on that buffer
    Do some work
}
```

When profiling my code I've come to realize that the time I spend executing FFTW is either about 5 seconds, 8 seconds, or 12 seconds (give or take a half a second, but it is generally 1 of those 3 numbers) depending on the run.

For each thread I am allocating the buffers with `_align_malloc(x, 16)` (though `fftw_malloc` gave me similar results) and then creating my 6 plans (one forward, one backward, for each buffer) only once at the start of the program using `FFTW_PATIENT`.

Why would my results vary from run to run like that?

Comment: "roughly 3k x 3k" Are the sizes consistent?  Power-of-2 is fastest, non-power-of-2 speed depends greatly on whether the size can be factored into small primes.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, the buffers that I allocate where I am doing the FFTs are actually 256x256 or 512x512, I'm only working on pieces of the larger vector at a time.

Comment: Any thoughts, or clarifications needed?

Answer (score 0):

Large FFT performance can often be mainly defendant on data cache hit ratios and miss penalties.  One possibility is, depending on which threads are allocated to which CPU cores, how the data is striped in memory, and the exact order and time at which the FFTs are started, the FFTs could be fighting over processor data cache lines, one thread flushing anothers state in some semi-deterministic thrash.

Comment: Thanks!

So that leaves the question of what is the best way to proceed. Would it make sense to try to set the affinity of each thread to its own logical processor and then try to allocate the space for the arrays in some way to compliment that? Or would it be better to try to synchronize the threads such that they aren't all hitting the FFT portion of the code at the same time?

Comment: Also, I am using some SIMD intrinsics in the work I am doing outside of the FFTs. I know that FFTW uses intrinsics as well, could this be causing any issues? I was never able to tell if the 16 SIMD registers that exist in x64 mode are per-core or per-logical-core (on a hyperthreaded machine). So I'm not sure if I might be causing issues having to save and restore register states as both code paths execute on a HT core. Though my code seems to take a relatively set amount of time with no variance, so that would make me think that isn't the case.